# utf8プラグマを付けると 受け取った内容の一部が文字化けます。

Tags: perl

CGIモジュールを利用して、フォームを作成しているのですが、入力画面からフォームの内容を受け取る際、utf8プラグマを付けると
受け取った内容の一部が 文字化けます。

以下のようにパラメーターを取得しています。
どうしたらよいでしょうか
現象はLaten-1の文字コードが表示されてしまいます。

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use Encode;
use Encode::Guess;
use Encode::EUCJPMS;
#use Jcode;
use CGI;
use utf8;
my $cgi = new CGI;
require 'mimew.pl';        # jcode($subject)->mime_encode が動かないとき
#エラーメッセージをブラウザに表示
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);
use Data::Dumper;
###################################
print "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\n\n";
# 項目名
my @item_names = ();
# 項目の日本語表示名
my %item_disp = ();
# 項目の値
my %item_value = ();
# 項目の必須有無
my %item_need = ();
# フォームパラメータ
my %fm_param = ();
my $cgi_url = $cgi->url();# このCGIのURL

#######################################################################
# 入力文字コード判定
#######################################################################
my $input_value = '';
my $name;
my $value;
my @values;
foreach $name ($cgi->param) {
if ($name !~ /^submit$/i) {# 項目('submit'は除く)
@values = $cgi->param($name);
$value = join(',', @values);
if($cgi->param('fm_command') eq 'confsend') {# 確認フォームからのときデコード
    $value = pack_param($value);
}
$input_value .= $value;
}
}
#エラーメッセージ配列
my @err_namelist = ();

#送信データがなければエラーとする
if (0 == length($input_value)) {
push(@err_namelist, '呼び出しエラーです。管理者にお問い合わせ下さい。');
print_input_error(@err_namelist);
exit;
}

#$input_jcode = Jcode::getcode($input_value);
my $guess = guess_encoding($input_value, qw/euc-jp shiftjis 7bit-jis/);
my $guess_encode = ($guess->name eq 'euc-jp') ? 'eucJP-ms' : $guess->name;

#######################################################################
# パラメータ読み込み
#######################################################################

my @checkboxes_array;

foreach $name ($cgi->param) {
if ($name =~ /^fm_/) {# フォームパラメータ
$value = $cgi->param($name);
if($cgi->param('fm_command') eq 'confsend') {# 確認フォームからのときデコード
    $value = pack_param($value);
}
#$value = jcode($value, $input_jcode)->sjis;
$value = ($guess->name ne 'shiftjis') ? encode('utf8', decode($guess_encode, $value)) : $value;
$fm_param{$name} = $value;
if($name =~ /^fm_disp_(\w+)/) {# 項目の日本語表示名
    $item_disp{$1} = $value;
    if(!defined $item_value{$1}) {
    push(@item_names, $1);
    $item_disp{$name} = ($guess->name ne 'shiftjis') ? encode('utf8', decode($guess_encode, $value)) : $value;

    $item_value{$1} = '';

    }
} elsif($name =~ /^fm_need_(\w+)/) {# 項目の入力必須
    $item_need{$1} = $value;
}
} elsif($name !~ /^submit$/i) {# 項目('submit'は除く)
if(!defined $item_value{$name}) {
    push(@item_names, $name);
}
@values = $cgi->param($name);

my $len = @values;
if ($len > 1) {
    logger($name . 'はチェックボックスなのです！で項目数は' . $len . 'なのです！(ただし複数選択可能なselectタグかもしれない・・・けど項目の上限を決めておけばいい($lenが上限以下ならselectでも項目をCSVに出す等))');
    for (my $k=0; $k<$len; $k++) {
    logger(@values[$k]);
    }
    #MEMO:
    #確認画面で項目数がここでわかったので、後ろの画面に$nameは$len項目ですと渡せばcsvでいい感じにできるのです！
    #実際の処理には現状確認画面でスペース？区切りか何かにされてしまっているため、項目数がうまくは取れないと思われる(確認画面のhiddenタグ参照の事)
    my $object = {
    name => $name,
    len => $len,
    #values => @values,
    values => [],
    };
    for (my $k=0; $k<$len; $k++) {
    logger(@values[$k]);
    push(@{$object->{values}}, @values[$k]);
    }
    push(@checkboxes_array, $object);
}

$value = join(',', @values);
if($cgi->param('fm_command') eq 'confsend') {# 確認フォームからのときデコード
    $value = pack_param($value);
}

#$item_value{$name} = jcode($value, $input_jcode)->sjis;
$item_value{$name} = ($guess->name ne 'shiftjis') ? encode('utf8', decode($guess_encode, $value)) : $value;
if($item_disp{$name} eq '') {
    $item_disp{$name} = $name;

}
}
}

my $len = @checkboxes_array;
if ($len > 0) {
logger('新規オブジェクト配列は' . $len);
for (my $i=0; $i<$len; $i++) {
logger(@checkboxes_array[$i]->{name});
logger(Dumper @checkboxes_array[$i]);
}
}


$value= decode('utf-8', $value);
foreach  my  $key (@item_names) {
#print $item_disp{$_} .':'.$item_value{$_};
$name = conv_html($item_disp{$key});
$value = conv_html($item_value{$key});

}
exit;

### csvに書けるように変換
sub conv_csv {
my ($str) = @_;
#$str =~ s/</&lt;/g;
#$str =~ s/>/&gt;/g;
$str =~ s/\t//g;
$str =~ s/\r//g;
$str =~ s/\n//g;
$str =~ s/\,/"\,\"/g;
#$str =~ s/"/""/g;
return '"' . $str . '"';
#return '' . $str . '';
}
sub conv_tsv {
my ($str) = @_;
#$str =~ s/</&lt;/g;
#$str =~ s/>/&gt;/g;
$str =~ s/\t//g;
$str =~ s/\r//g;
$str =~ s/\n//g;
$str =~ s/\,/"\t\"/g;
#$str =~ s/"/""/g;
return '"' . $str . '"';
#return '' . $str . '';
}

### htmlで表示できるように変換
sub conv_html {
my ($str) = @_;

$str =~ s/</&lt;/g;
$str =~ s/>/&gt;/g;
$str =~ s/\t//g;
$str =~ s/\r//g;
$str =~ s/\,/&nbsp;/g;
$str =~ s/\n/<br>\n/g;

return $str;
}

### htmlで表示できるように変換
sub conv_html2 {
my ($str) = @_;

$str =~ s/</&lt;/g;
$str =~ s/>/&gt;/g;
$str =~ s/\t//g;
$str =~ s/\r//g;
#$str =~ s/\,/&nbsp;/g;
$str =~ s/\n/<br>\n/g;

return $str;
}
sub conv_mail {
my ($str) = @_;
#$str =~ s/</&lt;/g;
#$str =~ s/>/&gt;/g;
$str =~ s/\t//g;
$str =~ s/\r//g;
$str =~ s/\n//g;
$str =~ s/\,/"\t\"/g;
#$str =~ s/"/""/g;
return '"' . $str . '"';
#return '' . $str . '';
}

### hiddenパラメータに格納できるようにエンコード
sub unpack_param {
my ($str) = @_;

$str =~ s/([^\w.\/\-@ ])/'%'.unpack('H2',$1)/eg;

return $str;
}

### エンコードしたhiddenパラメータをデコード
sub pack_param {
my ($str) = @_;

$str =~ s/%([A-Fa-f0-9]{2})/pack('H2', $1)/eg;

return $str;
}

sub conv_ahtml {
my ($str) = @_;
#$str =~ s/</&lt;/g;
#$str =~ s/>/&gt;/g;
$str =~ s/\t//g;
$str =~ s/\r//g;
$str =~ s/\n/<br>\n/g;

return $str;
}
```

Comment: ご使用の Perlのバージョンはいくつでしょうか ?

Comment: perl 5.8とPelr5.10です。

Comment: どちらも同じ現象ですか？utf8 プラグマを設定した時の pack の動作が 5.10 で変わったのでその影響があるかもしれません。 http://kawa.at.webry.info/200801/article_11.html

Comment: 再現できるようにしました。
以下のようなHTMLを作成し、Perlにたたいていただくと。

<form name="form1" method="post" action="test.cgi" id="form_id">
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="名前" size="30">
に対応するパラメーター
<input type="hidden" name="fm_disp_name" id="fm_disp_name" value="お名前">
<input type="hidden" name="fm_need_name" id="fm_need_name" value="1">
</form>

受け取ったi　name属性に対応した。　パラメータに分解されます。

Comment: Hashに置き換えたときに文字化けているように思います。

Comment: まず、質問内容を動くコードに修正してもらえますか？ 92行目は明らかにシンタックスエラーになっています ` for (my $k=0; $k $name,`

Comment: 修正しました。
preタグ記法で貼り付けてしまい（）が抜け落ちてしまいました。

Comment: @Motoki, printはContent-Typeのところだけ？ CGIスクリプトとフォームのあるHTMLの文字コードはそれぞれ何ですか？

Comment: それぞれutf8の出力です。

Comment: うーん・・・再現しませんでした。ブラウザからアクセスした時に、test.cgi?fm_disp_name=1&fm_need_name=1&name=%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E8%AA%9E、だと文字化けしますか？

Comment: マルチポスト先で解決済み　https://teratail.com/questions/22678

Answer (score 1):

Perlで「UTF-8」というとき、外部とやりとりする文字コードとしてのUTF-8を指す場合と、Perlの内部文字コードとしてのUTF-8を指す場合があります。まぎらわしいですが、両者はいっしょにできない別物です。Perlの文字列として見た場合、前者はバイト列、後者は内部コード列になります。

上のコードをざっと見た限りでは、日本語文字列をバイト列として扱っているように見えます。いっぽう、utf8プラグマは、文字列を内部文字コード列として扱う宣言です。

そのため、utf8プラグマを付けないか（バイト列ベース）、入ってくる文字列をdecodeして出ていく文字列をencodeするよう全体を変更するか（内部文字コード列ベース）、どちらか合わせることになると思います。

Comment: HTMLのname属性について日本語を通したく、考えたところ、utf8にした際、正しく正規表現にかからない問題があり、utf8プラグマを付けてみたというところです。

Comment: とすると、上のコードを内部文字コード列ベースの処理に変えたいというのがご要望ですね。それには、ぱっと見て、いくつか変更する必要のある箇所があります。ただ、上のコードは壊れているようなので（カッコが閉じられていない箇所など）、具体的にはなんとも。

Comment: ダブルクオーテーションで囲まれた文字で変数を表示すると文字化けるという違いが判りました、
utf8プラグマを付けずに（バイト列ベース）で、htmlにあるinput要素のname属性を日本語化した際にマッチングさせることは可能でしょうか？

Comment: 一般論としては、バイト列ベースでも、文字列のバイト列で使われている文字コードとスクリプトの文字コードが同じであれば、そのまま日本語の正規表現マッチングは使えます（Shift JIS系で2バイト目の文字が特殊な意味を持ってしまうなどのトラップはありますが）。

そういう意味では、上のコードは、条件によって文字列がShift JISのバイト列だったりUTF-8のバイト列だったりするので、そこがマッチングを困難にするかもしれません。

Answer (score 1):

最後の出力の前に、`utf8::decode($value)`を行ってみてください。

詳しい理由は、下記サイトを参照してください。

一部引用：

> use utf8 とは、 このCGIスクリプト内で扱う全角文字は文字コードがUTF-8であり、且つ、扱う全角文字データ全てにutf8フラグ（目印みたいなもの／以下単に「フラグ」と呼称）を付けてあるのでそのつもりで処理してね、とPerl側に教えてやる宣言のこと。

PerlのCGIのutf-8改造で文字化けしたときの処方箋
http://mycc.s33.xrea.com/data/pc/perl_use_utf8.html

Comment: 入れてみましたが、文字化けてしまします。